# Post-hoc test for a glmer model fitting a paired sample, repeated measures, poison distribution

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, post-hoc

I have paired sample dataset where the same sample received Treatment('Drug A','Placebo') on different days and i am comparing the effects of my response variable (i.e. Left_Pokes) per minute (i.e. Time_min) when exposed to a device for 1 hour. I want to test whether the Treatment has any effects on Left_pokes which the number of Left_pokes were recorded per minute within the 1 hour experiment time. If no pokes are made, Left_pokes = 0.

Dataframe example:

```
sample <- 9
Treatment <- c(rep("Drug A", sample), rep("placebo", sample))
Time_mins <- rep(0:60, each = sample * 2)
Left_Pokes <- rpois(sample * 2 * 61, lambda = 1)
df <- data.frame(sample, Treatment, Time_mins, Left_Pokes)
```

I've ran a shapiro-Wilk's test and it came back as non-normally distributed, so because my response variable is count data, i am setting my glmer model as a "Poisson" distribution. My current code for post-hoc test is using bonferroni as it doesnt require normality.

I just want to ask whether the below code is correct to run this specific glmer and then a bonferroni post-hoc to see which time-point significance is occuring? i want to use the pval to show signficance on my line plot graph.

```
model<-glmer(Left_Pokes~Time_mins*Treatment + (1|sample),data=df,family="poisson")
stats<-Anova(model, type = "II")
stats<-get_anova_table(stats)
pwc1<-df%>%group_by(Time_mins)%>%
      pairwise_t_test(Left_Pokes~Treatment,paired=TRUE,p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible: `sample` doesn't occur later on and the data frame `df` used in the model is not defined. Regarding the question: I'd look into the `emmeans` package.

Comment: Thanks, there was a typo and ive changed it